# Pourquoi "zéro'' article ?

Tags: articles, absence-d-article

Dans la phrase ci-dessous :

> J’ai enseigné à des personnes d'âges variés.

pourquoi faut-il dire d'âges et pas des âges ?

En plus, si l'on écrivait

> J’ai enseigné aux personnes...

l'autre partie de la phrase resterait la même ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La préposition *d'* joue ici le rôle d'un **article indéfini contracté**.

Comme résumé [ici](https://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/articles_de_du2.htm),

> DE + DES => D' *(voyelle)*

La question se pose :

**Pourquoi un article indéfini contracté et pas un article défini contracté ("*des âges*") ?**

Tout simplement parce qu'étant donné le contexte de la phrase, on considère que "les âges" ne sont pas définis. On parle de différents âges, quels qu'ils soient (indéfinis), pour souligner la pluralité des personnes auxquelles le narrateur a enseigné.